# Encoding list of objects as JSON object

Tags: python, json, matlab

I would like to extend the standard library Python [JSON encoder](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to encode lists of complex numbers into a representation correctly parsed by [JSONLAB](http://iso2mesh.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/index.cgi?jsonlab), the unofficial JSON toolbox for MATLAB.  Briefly, a single Python complex number `(x + yj)` should be encoded as a JSON complex number object,

```
{"_ArrayType_": "double",
 "_ArraySize_": [1, 1],
 "_ArrayIsComplex_": 1,
 "_ArrayData_": [x, y]}
```

and a list of complex numbers `[(x1 + y1j), (x2+y2j), (x3+y3j)]` should *also* become a single JSON complex number object,

```
{"_ArrayType_": "double",
 "_ArraySize_": [1, 3],
 "_ArrayIsComplex_": 1,
 "_ArrayData_": [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]]}
```

I have been able to correctly encode a single complex number, like so:

```
class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, complex):
            return {"_ArrayType_": "double", "_ArraySize_": [1, 1],
                    "_ArrayIsComplex_": 1, "_ArrayData_": [obj.real, obj.imag]}
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

I tried a straightforward extension to the case of a complex number list, but it does not quite work:

```
class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        # if obj is a list containing at least one complex number
        if isinstance(obj, list) and sum(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, complex),
                                             obj)):
            data = [[elem.real, elem.imag] for elem in obj]
            return {"_ArrayType_": "double", "_ArraySize_": [1, len(obj)],
                    "_ArrayIsComplex_": 1, "_ArrayData_": data}
        elif isinstance(obj, complex):
            return {"_ArrayType_": "double", "_ArraySize_": [1, 1],
                    "_ArrayIsComplex_": 1, "_ArrayData_": [obj.real, obj.imag]}
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

If this class is used to parse a Python list of complex numbers, the result is a JSON list of 1x1 JSON complex number objects, rather than a single JSON complex number object.  It seems that the Python object is parsed "bottom-up," rather than "top-down," with the complex numbers converted into 1x1 JSON complex number objects before it is noticed that they're in a list.

How best to encode lists of complex numbers into complex number objects compatible with JSONLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From taking a brief look through the [`simplejson`](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/blob/master/simplejson/encoder.py) source code, there seems to be no easy way to encode the JSON in any way other than bottom up. I'd suggest two possible solutions:

- Using a non-iterable or non-list object (i.e. something that the `json` module doesn't parse) to contain the list of complex numbers, so that it will be encoded by `default()` and not `json.JSONEncoder`.
- Encode the lists of complex numbers before encoding the rest, so that the json encoder doesn't' have to deal with encoding parent objects before child objects.

Comment: Your first suggestion solved my problem: I replaced Python lists with numpy arrays.  In addition to not being parsed by the `json` module, they're more natural candidates for eventual conversion into MATLAB vectors.